# Inverse of a matrix with $a+1$ on the diagonal and $a$ in other places

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $a>0$. Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with $a+1$ on the diagonal and $a$ in all other entries. How can one compute $A^{-1}$ as a function of $n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $A$ as $I + aJ$ where $J$ is the matrix consisting of all $1$s.  Now using the fact that $J^2 = nJ$, look for an inverse of the form $c_1I + c_2J$.  More generally, there is the famous [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%2dMorrison_formula) for rank-one perturbations of invertible matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $J$ be an $n$ by$n$ matrix all whose entries are 1. Then the answer is  $I-aJ/(1+an)$. as you can verify.   To motivate and get to this formula look up a series expansion for $(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$A = I_n + a 1_n 1_n^T$$

Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),

$$A^{-1} = I_n - \left(\frac{a}{1 + a 1_n^T 1_n}\right) 1_n 1_n^T = I_n - \left(\frac{a}{1 + n a}\right) 1_n 1_n^T$$