# How to find this determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 + 2 a_1 & a_1 +   a_2 & a_1+a_3 &  \cdots & a_1+a_n\\
        a_2 + a_1 & 1   + 2 a_2 & a_2+a_3 &  \cdots & a_2+a_n\\
        a_3 + a_1 & a_3 +   a_2 & 1+2a_3 &  \cdots & a_3+a_n\\
        \vdots    & \vdots      & \vdots &  \ddots &\vdots\\
        a_n + a_1 & a_n +   a_2 & a_n+a_3 &  \cdots & 1+2a_n\\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

Most likely there is a very simple solution here, but I just can’t see it. Please give me some hints. I tried subtracting the first row from all the others and then subtracting the last column from all the columns, it seemed like I was close, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: you can write it as identity plus a 2 rank symmetric matrix

Comment: @Exodd I am new to Linear algebra and trying to figure out how this hint helps. $\det(A+I)$ where $A$ is symmetric and $\text{rank}(A)=2$. But I don't think $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ so the answer is non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote  $b=(1,\ldots,1)^T$,  $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^T$, and $A=ab^T+ba^T.$ Assume for a while that $a$ and $b$ are independent. Consider the two dimensional space $F\subset R^n$ generated by $a$ and $b$ and compute $A(\alpha a+\beta b)$ in order to

1. observe that $F$ is stable by $A$
2. prove that the two eigenvalues of $A$ restricted to $F$ are $\langle a,b\rangle\pm\|a\|\|b\|.$

Finally $A$ is a symmetric matrix and any vector $v$ orthogonal to $F$ satisfies $Av=0.$ As a result the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\langle a,b\rangle\pm\|a\|\|b\|$ and $0$ with multiplicity $n-2.$ The eigenvalues of $I+A$ are $1+\langle a,b\rangle\pm\|a\|\|b\|$ and $1$ with multiplicity $n-2.$ The determinant of $I+A$ is $$(1+\langle a,b\rangle)^2-\|a\|^2\|b\|^2.$$ If $a$ and $b$ are dependent, the result is still true, by considering $a^k$ and $b^k$ independent such that $a^k\to_ka$ and $b^k\to _k b.$

Sorry for offering a standard solution for a student of second year, and not a clever one for a student of first year (that I have not really looked for).

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\bf a} := \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix}^\top$. Using [Weinstein-Aronszajn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$ \det \left( {\bf I}_n + {\bf a} {\bf 1}_n^\top + {\bf 1}_n {\bf a}^\top \right) = \cdots = 1 - n \, \underbrace{{\bf a}^\top \left( {\bf I}_n - \frac{{\bf 1}_n {\bf 1}_n^\top}{n} \right) {\bf a}}_{= \operatorname{Var} ({\bf a})} + 2 \,{\bf 1}_n^\top {\bf a} $$

where $\operatorname{Var} ({\bf a})$ denotes the [variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697657/339790) of $\bf a$.

Comment: In W-A, what are the $A, B$ that  you consider for the above application?

Comment: @GérardLetac $n \times 2$ matrices whose columns are $\bf a$ and ${\bf 1}_n$. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2353527/339790)