# Is an $n\times n$ matrix where the diagonals are equal to one and the off diagonals all have magnitude smaller than one always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have an $n\times n$ matrix where the diagonals are equal to one and the off diagonals all have magnitude smaller than one. Is this matrix invertible? What is the quickest way to prove it?

Comment: I know a **very special case** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

Comment: Sorry, I confused diagonal and off-diagonal - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312849/matrix-with-zeros-on-diagonal-and-ones-in-other-places-is-invertible). Just a question: is the exercise perhaps with *absolute value* smaller than one?

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&-1/2&-1/2\\-1/2&1&-1/2\\-1/2&-1/2&1}$ is not invertible.

Comment: No, take $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &-0.5&0.5\\-0.5&1&0.5\\0.5&0.5&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: in addition, OP should consider $\mathbf X$ which has n columns each with norm 1 but only $k\lt n$ of them are linearly independent (and no column is equal to another column or equal to another rescaled by -1).  Then $\mathbf X^T\mathbf X$ is a matrix with diagonals of 1 and each off diagonal element has modulus less than 1 (e.g. apply Cauchy Schwarz or law of cosines) yet $\text{rank}\big(\mathbf X^T\mathbf X\big) =\text{rank}\big(\mathbf X\big) = k\lt n$